# Wrong type or number of parameters when calling a PL/SQL function using Java. PLS-00306 error

Tags: java, plsql

```
try{
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log(p_user IN VARCHAR2, p_password IN VARCHAR2, p_name IN VARCHAR2 ) "
                    + "RETURN number "
                    + "IS "
                    + "flag login%ROWTYPE; "
                    + "temp number; "
                    + "BEGIN "
                    + "select username into flag "
                    + "from login "
                    + "where username=p_user and password=p_password and name=p_name; "
                    + "IF (sql%found) THEN temp:= 1; "
                    + "ELSE temp:= 0; "
                    + "END IF; "
                    + "return temp; "
                    + "END; ");

            stmt.close();

            String value = Combo_Name.getSelectedItem().toString();

            String sql= "begin "
                    + "?:=log(?,?,?); "
                    + "end; ";

            CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall (sql);

            cstmt.registerOutParameter (1, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
            cstmt.setString(2, user_id.getText());
            cstmt.setString (3, password.getText()); 
            cstmt.setString(4, value);

            cstmt.execute();

            int check =cstmt.getInt(1);

             if(check==1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successful");
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username or Password");
            }

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

A `pls-00306` error is shown when I am calling the function. Every time it shows wrong type or numbers of parameters. Please help me to resolve the errors. The variable value is used to take input from the combo box.

Comment: The "log" function......i am passing the exact number of parameters and each parameter corresponds to the exact match of datatype but still it is showing PLS-00306 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clashing with a built-in function [`LOG(n2,n1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions085.htm#i84140) that returns the **logarithm**, base `n2`, of `n1`.

Use another name.